# searchBar not searching and not filtering

Tags: swift, searchbar

I've referenced https://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/ to follow how searchBar works.  I have followed to the tee, but when typing something in the searchBar, it is not filtering the results.  Here is the code.  Can you please help? Thanks.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var data = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]
    var filtered:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Setup delegates */
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
            let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
        return data.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell;
        if(searchActive){
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row];
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're on swift 3, it should be func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)

Answer (score 0):

I found out my answer to this.  I had to delete the bindings for the IBOutlet for searchBar and tableView.  Then I had to re-add them again.  Not sure why it's like this, but it definitely worked.